# how can i print in json group name for each group value

Tags: java, json

I am very much new to java, actually I am converting a Json file to XML. It is working fine but group name is not printing for each group value in the sense. I have Json like this

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "r": "y",
    "g1": [
        {
            "gg1": 1,
            "gg2": 2,
            "gg3": 3
        },
        {
            "gg4": 4",
            "gg5": 5",
            "gg6": 6"
        }
    ]
}
```

i am using this java code which i got from net

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ConvertJSONtoXMLSetRoot {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = ConvertJSONtoXMLSetRoot.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json file");
    String jsonData = IOUtils.toString(is);

    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
    JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonData ); 
    serializer.setRootName("SampleJSON");
    serializer.setTypeHintsEnabled(false);
    String xml = serializer.write( json );  
    System.out.println(xml);        

}
```

}

Actually it print s in this format

```
<a>b</a>
<r>y</r>
<g1>
    <e>
        <gg1>1</gg1>
        <gg2>2</gg2>
        <gg3>3</gg3>
    </e>
    <e>
        <gg4>4</gg4>
        <gg5>5</gg5>
        <gg6>6</gg6>
    </e>
</g1>
```

But i want output in this format

```
<a>b</a>
<r>y</r>
<g1>
    <gg1>1</gg1>
    <gg2>2</gg2>
    <gg3>3</gg3>
</g1>
<g1>
    <gg4>4</gg4>
    <gg5>5</gg5>
    <gg6>6</gg6>
</g1>
```

I dont no whether I have to change code or to change Json structure, please help me anyone

Comment: You have invalid JSON; paste your JSON in `jsonlint.com` and you'll see that you have an unenclosed value(s).

Comment: @f0x i tried editing its not accepting, i changed it many times so, can u help me ignoring those errors